# Can't convert raw to wav using SoX

Tags: sox

Try as I may, I am unable to successfully use SoX to convert a raw file to a wav file.

The command line I use is:

```
sox -r 44100 -b 16 -e signed-integer c -1 -t raw   000000.raw 1.wav
```

What I get back is static.  And to even make sure I've got the input file data correct when I import it with Audacity I use the settings:

Signed 16bit PCM
Big-endian
1 Channel (mono)
Sample rate 44100

and the output on that works just fine.

If anyone is familiar with SoX I would appreciate any hints,

Thanks

p.s.   Here is the link to the raw file

[1.raw](http://98.7.37.117)

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with your command. Without access to the raw file it is impossible to help any further. On this site we value very highly reproducible code.

Comment: @AkselA I've added a link to download the raw file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Endianness seems to be the issue.
By default it is taken to be little endian, but by including the `-B` flag the data is read as big endian.

```
sox -t raw -r 44100 -b 16 -e signed-integer -B -c 1 000000.raw test2.wav
```